# Network bridge from Win8 to Win7 not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-bridge

As requested from every tutorial I've followed, I've disabled Internet Connection Sharing, connected both computers using the proper Ethernet cable--but every time I try to initiate I get the "You need to select at least two LAN or high-speed internet connections..." message.

I am absolutely selecting the two networks I want to bridge, but it still gives me this error every time. What gives?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. Instead post the steps that fixed it as an answer.